# Confusion with how indexOf works in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was trying to learn how to properly work with indexOf in JS, that is, if you look at the code below:

```
var sandwiches = ['turkey', 'ham', 'turkey', 'tuna', 'pb&j', 'ham', 'turkey', 'tuna'];

var deduped = sandwiches.filter(function (sandwich, index) {
    return sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index;
});

// Logs ["turkey", "ham", "tuna", "pb&j"]
console.log(deduped);
```

I am trying to remove duplicates but wanted to ask two questions. Firstly, in here return sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index; why we need to use "== index;". Secondly, since indexOf returns index like 0, 1 or 2 ... then why when we console.log(deduped) we get array of names instead of array of indexes. Hope you got my points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a method of Javascript Array that is `filter`, this method take a function that returns a boolean.

The function `filter` returns a new Array based on the function passed applied to each entry.

If the function return true, then the entry is included in the new Array, otherwise is discarded.

As the functions check the indexOf an entry to be the current index is true for the first occurrency of the entry.

All the duplications will fail the expression as they are not the first index found by indexOf, so they are discarded.

Comment: hi Mario, I meant to say why we equalize return sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index; indexOf to index?

Comment: indexOf returns the index of the element if it found, otherwise it returns -1. If you have a duplicate, indexOf will return the first occurrence index each time, so if your duplication is on index 5, i.e, and you have the first occurrence at index 3, you get: 3 === 5 that is false, and the duplicate is discarded.

Comment: thank you Mario for your kind comments, can I imagine it like this, if you look at my code above, when we start iterating over sandwiches, the first on the array is "turkey". Then, this code sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index; will be like 0 ===0 which is true then turkey is added into array. Then when it comes to the next "turkey", this code sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index; will not be 2===2 but will be 0===2 since iterator will look to the first "turkey". Is that right? Hope you got my point:)

Comment: my very last question is Since indexOf returns index rather than name of element in an array, In our sandwiches case, ultimately indexOf returns 0,1,3,4. Then since these indexes are put into array(which will be returned by filter), why we get names of elements in that returned array instead of [0,1,3,4]? Thank you

Comment: The filter function returns the new array, and that array will contain elements from the original array, while the function provided as the filter argument, is just used to decide which of the original array elements will be inserted in the new array. That function return a boolean.

Comment: thank you Mario for your kind explanation:), sorry you missed my penultimate question. Just need your confirmation, That is it, thank you:)

Comment: @Dickens about your penultimate question, I confirm you're right.

Answer (score 3):

1. since the logic is to remove the duplicates from the array,
   in your example, you have "turkey" as duplicates. 
   the "turkey" exists in position 0,2,6
   so whenever you call indexOf("turkey") always returns 0 because the indexOf function returns the first occurrence of a substring. 
   so for the elements in position 2 & 6 the condition fails. then it won't return that element.
2. That is how the filter works in javascript. it evaluates the condition and returns true or false that indicates whether an element to be included in the new array or not, in your example the condition is `return sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index;`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the basic logic is easier to see at a glance if you use arrow notation:

```
const deduped = myArray => myArray.filter((x, i) => myArray.indexOf(x) === i);
```

The key point is that `indexOf` returns the index of the *first* occurrence of `x`. For that occurrence the result of the comparison will be true hence the element will be retained by the filter. For any subsequent occurrence the comparison will be false and the filter will reject it.

Comment: hey John thanks for your kind answer, I just wanted to ask one question. Since indexOf returns index rather than name of element in an array, In our sandwiches case, ultimately indexOf returns 0,1,3,4. Then since these indexes are put into array(which will be returned by filter), why we get names of elements in that returned array instead of [0,1,3,4]? Thank you

Comment: @Dickens  Neither `indexOf` or the comparison `myArray.indexOf(x) === i` are the return value of the overall function. The overall function returns `myArray.filter( .... )` You are fixating on the condition inside the filter. When you filter an array of strings, of course you get an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Difference between `===` (identity) and `==` (equality): if type of compared values are different then `===` will return false, while `==` will try to convert values to the same type. So, in cases where you compare some values with known types it is better to use `===`. (http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm)
2. You get as result an array of names instead of array of indexes because `Array.filter` do not change the values, but only filter them. The filter function in your case is  `return sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index;` which return `true` or `false`. If you want get the indexes of your items after deduplication, then use `map` after filter:

```
a.filter(...).map(function(item, idx) {return idx;})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dikens, `indexOf` gives the index of the element if found. And if the element is not found then it returns `-1`.

In your case you are filtering the array and storing the values in the `deduped`. That's why it is showing an array.

If you console the indexOf in the filter function then it will log the index of the element.

For example :

```
var deduped = sandwiches.filter(function (sandwich, index) {
   console.log(sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich));
   return sandwiches.indexOf(sandwich) === index;
});
```